# More Efficient Summarise / Summarize in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have code which executes a large number of summarise and it takes ages to run.

eg:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Letter = letters, Num = c(1 : (26*10) ))

for (x in 1:10000){
  df_sum_Tot = summarise(df, Sum_Num = sum(Num)  )
  df_sum_Letter = summarise(df, Sum_Num = sum(Num) , .by =  Letter )

}
```

Is there a more efficient alternative to summarise I could use to speed it up?

Comment: Why are you executing the same two summaries 10000 times?

Comment: @Limey maybe they have 10000 different datasets, or 10000 columns to summarise.

Comment: @Limey, that's just example code, not the real thing. My actual code does the same summarise, but with thousands of different datasets.

Comment: (1) You could try parallelism to speed things up. Take a look at the `doParallel` and `foreach`package. (2) Based on your example, you could first create `df_sum_Letter` and a next step create `df_sum_tot` based on `df_sum_letter`. Your code calculates them independently.

Comment: *"thousands of different datasets"* is very very different than "thousands of rows in one dataset". If you have thousands of different objects (e.g., `x1`, `x2`, ..., `x1000`) and they are all the same structure, you will gain significant speed improvments by combining them into one dataset (preserving, if needed, the source object so that they are still perfectly distinguishable) and adding the source object name as a grouping variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with thousands of different datasets, you could put them all into a list and use `lapply` to summarise them all, rather than using a `for` loop.

Other packages can also be much more efficient for summarising than `dplyr`, especially with large datasets. For example, `data.table` or `collapse`:

```
# Assuming datasets is your list of all your data.frames:
# Using data.table
library(data.table)
results <- lapply(datasets, function(df) {
  setDT(df) 
  df_sum_Tot <- df[, .(Sum_Num = sum(Num))]
  df_sum_Letter <- df[, .(Sum_Num = sum(Num)), by = Letter]
  list(Total = df_sum_Tot, ByLetter = df_sum_Letter)
})

# Using collapse:
library(collapse)
results <- lapply(datasets, function(df) {
  df <- as.data.table(df)  
  df_sum_Tot <- collap(df, Sum_Num = fsum(Num))
  df_sum_Letter <- collap(df, Sum_Num = fsum(Num), by = "Letter")
  list(Total = df_sum_Tot, ByLetter = df_sum_Letter)
})
```